# How can you assign multiple string values to an attribute in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name="Customer", limit_choices_to={'is_staff': False})
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    # locations =  What should go here?
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    website_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

As you can see here, I have a locations field which. This field is to store at most 5 locations the business is located in. How can I best achieve this?

I have read about using a Many2Many field but this would not be desirable as the locations would have to be first created in the Admin and then added to the business.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the locations would have to be added in the Admin panel first.  ManyToManyField is indeed the way to go.

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name="Customer", limit_choices_to={'is_staff': False})
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    locations =  models.ManyToManyField(Location)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    website_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Then you can add locations to the Customer in your view:

```py
def home(request):
    # First create the customer
    customer = Customer.objects.create_user(user=request.user)
    
    # Then get the locations
    # I'm assuming you'll get this from a form post request
    locations = request.POST.getlist('locations')

    for location in locations:
        Location.objects.create(location=location)
        customer.add(location)
```

Check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/relations/) for more information.

Comment: Yes, this would work if there were locations already in the locations table. However, I would like for the locations to be added when creating a new customer.

Comment: @NevilleOtieno, I've edited my answer.  True, using the ManyToManyField you can not add them until the Customer is created.  There might be another way, but I just don't see it.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will implement this unless I find an alternative way.

Comment: I followed this [link] (https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/django-manytomanyfield-via-comma-separated-string) and got very good results as to almost what I expected in case anyone is also looking for a solution to this.

Comment: If you get it to work for what you need, then you should post an answer to your question.  You are allowed to answer your own question, @NevilleOtieno.

Answer (score 0):

Ifyou don't want `ManyToManyField` you could impose a bit of syntax on what is a valid Location, and store the locations in a single CharField with some separator character. You would use [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/) to make sure that things stay sane. If you are using PostgreSQL as your DB, you could make the locations into a JSONField or an ArrayField, but if you can't do that it's not too hard to use a plain CharField

```
MAX_LOCATIONS = 5
LOCATIONS_SEPARATOR = '||'
MAX_LOCATION_LENGTH = 200

locations = models.CharField( max_length= MAX_LOCATIONS*(MAX_LOCATION_LENGTH + len(LOCATIONS_SEPARATOR) ), 
   validators = [LocationsValidator, ],
   ...
)
...

def LocationsValidator( value):
if len( value.split( LOCATION_SEPARATOR )) > MAX_LOCATIONS
    raise ValidationError(
        f'Location value represents more than maximum {MAX_LOCATIONS} locations'
    )
```

Use the Python string `.split` and `.join` methods to convert from a single location string and a list of up to 5 location values. Remember to validate location values in forms

```
valid = ( len( location) <= Customer.MAX_LOCATION_LENGTH and 
    Customer.LOCATIONS_SEPARATOR not in location )
```

`ManyToMany` will pay dividends should you ever wish to start associating other data with location values. Therefore, personally, I would not recommend the above in any common circumstance.